# Incomplete type works with gcc but not with clang and msvc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

I have recently learnt about incomplete types and that under certain conditions they can be used as template arguments. In particular, like `void`, `struct incomplete;` are both incomplete types. Then I wrote the following program that works with gcc but not with msvc and clang. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WGz3f75da)

```
struct incomplete;
template<typename T> struct C
{
    static constexpr T t{};
};

template<class T>
struct myClass {
    C<T> new_t() { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    myClass<incomplete> d;
    d.new_t();    
}
```

As we can see the above program compiles with gcc but not with msvc and clang. So I want to know which is the correct technical behavior.

Clang says:

```
<source>:4:24: error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const incomplete'
    static constexpr T t{};
```

while msvc says:

```
<source>(4): error C2027: use of undefined type 'incomplete'
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'incomplete'
```

while GCC accepts the code with both c++17 as well as c++20.

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: Interestingly, as soon as you odr-use `t`, gcc also rejects the code. This might be an indication as to why gcc accepts it in the first place.

Comment: Looks like ill-formed.

Comment: You need to "complete" the type eventually. Else the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

The program is **ill-formed** and *gcc is wrong in accepting the code* because even though the **definition** of the static data member is not instantiated(because it is not odr-used), it's **declaration** will still be instantiated due to the *implicit instantiation* of `C<incomplete>` as per [temp.inst#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#3). More importantly, if a **declaration** uses `constexpr` or `inline` (since C++17) specifier, the member must be declared to have complete type.

From [temp.inst#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#3):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes:
>
> - the **implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, of the** non-deleted class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members**, member templates, and friends; and

(emphasis mine)

This means that the implicit instantiation `C<incomplete>` will cause the implicit instantiation of the **declaration** of the static data member.

Further from [static data member documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

> However, if the declaration uses `constexpr` or `inline` (since C++17) specifier, the member **must be declared to have complete type**.

(emphasis mine)

This means that since the implicitly instantiated declaration, declares a member of an incomplete type, the program is **ill-formed**.

---

Here is the gcc bug report:

[static constexpr incomplete (depedent) data member of a class template and in-member initialized incorrectly accepted](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107945)

Comment: Yes, I think `[temp.inst]` is key to deciding whether `[basic.def]` even applies. +1

Comment: @bitmask Thanks, here is the [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107945).